# AdSense: How to keep Ads updated with logged in user content

Tags: asp.net, adsense

I want my Ads to work like Gmail, so it will show Ads according to the content of the user.  All the users on my site have to login to insert content.

I use AdSense site authentication and it works fine, I can see the crawler reading the pages.

I configured my site the following way:

Every time the user redirects to a page I added his ID so the request is :  X?id=123

And when the crawler user entered the same page, it shows a list of links to the same page with different IDs (each link shows different user content according to the ID) :

X?id=1

X?id=2

X?id=3 ….

It worked great !!  If for example the user entered cars content he got cars Ads.

But after a while it stopped working, Even though the crawler keeps reading the pages the Ads aren’t relevant to the user content.

Is there a way to keep updating the Ads? (The content the crawler sees keep updating)

Is there a better way of doing this?

I use: ASP.NET MSSQL 2005

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can a non-authenticated, non-javascript-running Bot that google is running see the context on these pages? Use Google Webmaster Tools ([tutorial](http://www.netregistry.com.au/news/articles/252/1/Google-Webmaster-Tools-See-what-Google-Sees/Page1.html)) to learn exactly what the googlebot sees on your site.

Comment: I'm using the Webmaster tools. It worked for a while so I think i'm on the right way. I just don't know how to keep it updated.